# Error Connecting to Service Protocol on Real Android Phone in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm working on bluetooth low energy with flutter. I updated flutter on android studio and so i have this error and this error write as :"Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to [http://127.0.0.1:52524"](http://127.0.0.1:52524%22) in run terminal so i could not run my program on real phone so how can i fix this problem, by the way my phone's android version is Android 5.0.1

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem in a device whose version is Android 5.0.1. Other devices work fine

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.